# pickle files loading time

Tags: python-3.x, pickle, benchmarking

I was just testing which file format suits my problem best and benchmarked a few formats. While doing this I stumbled upon the following, in my opinion, weird time difference when loading files.

I created a random large DataFrame for testing with the following code (since my problem uses time series data its also used in my example):

```
rows = 5000000
cols = 50

df = pd.DataFrame(
    data=np.random.rand(rows, cols),
    index=pd.date_range(
        start='2014-01-01',
        periods=rows,
        freq='min'
    ),
)
```

Then I saved the DataFrame using `df.to_pickle('test.pkl')` and started benchmarking the loading time. Since I am dealing with large datasets I also wanted to know how the loading time scales when only needing part of the time series. I mainly used this to see if other formats that are able to only load part of the file are able to get smaller loading times when doing so. Since pickle files need to be loaded completely I just included a `.loc[time_stamp:]` to get the same slicing in the end. These are my results:

```
In [1]: %timeit pd.read_pickle('test.pkl')
Out[1]: 1.94 s ± 182 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)
In [2]: %timeit pd.read_pickle('test.pkl').loc[pd.to_datetime('20200101 00:00'):]
Out[2]: 1.73 s ± 237 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)
```

I know the time differences are not large, but I tested this multiple times over the day and the second method (with slicing) is always the faster one. Which gets to my "problem". **Why is the loading method using `.loc[time_stamp:]` faster?** I thought both attempts are doing exactly the same thing, namely loading the whole pickle file. The only difference would be using approx. half of the DataFrame in the second approach, which shouldnt make a big difference. What am I missing?

Next question would be: Is this a way to actually save time when using pickle? Just slicing the DataFrame in the line I am loading it?

Hope someone can get some insights into this or maybe testing the same thing and proving me wrong with my observations.

Comment: Is there a reason you are using pickle over say [to_csv](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_csv.html) ?

Comment: Well as I wrote I am testing different file formats atm, but yes sometimes I prefer using pickle since its really fast with writing/reading compared to other formats.

Comment: It is a great question. I've tried to dig up something in [pandas' docs](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/blob/4bfe3d07b4858144c219b9346329027024102ab6/pandas/io/pickle.py#L119) but couldn't find anything relevant. I then assumed the optimisation was done on the pickle side, but it turns out that doing a similar operation
(`with open(file_path, "rb") as f:` followed by `pickle.load(f)[:50000000]`)
on an array is _slower_, so I really have no clue what's going on.

Answer (score 1):

I was suspicious of the accuracy of the `timeit`s, so I tried a similar approach, scaling up the DataFrame size a little bit :

```py
rows = 10000000
cols = 100
df = pd.DataFrame(
    data=np.random.rand(rows, cols),
    index=pd.date_range(
        start='2014-01-01',
        periods=rows,
        freq='min'
    ),
)
```

At first I could replicate your issue :

```
%timeit pd.read_pickle(F)
2.67 s ± 362 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)
%timeit pd.read_pickle(F).loc[pd.to_datetime('20200101 00:00'):]
2.51 s ± 30.2 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)
```

But it turns out we're simply being fooled by (I assume) processor caches ; the faster operation of the two is *always* the latest ; here I run the slicing one *before* the direct load :

```
%timeit pd.read_pickle(F).loc[pd.to_datetime('20200101 00:00'):]
2.87 s ± 879 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)
%timeit pd.read_pickle(F)
2.64 s ± 34.8 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)
```

If we run the `timeit`s a couple times more, we can see the expected result (the slicing one being just a little bit slower) :

```
%timeit pd.read_pickle(F).loc[pd.to_datetime('20200101 00:00'):]
2.66 s ± 87 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)
%timeit pd.read_pickle(F)
2.63 s ± 70.8 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)
```

Comment: Interesting, I will test your approach and see if I can reproduce. I thought I switched the order of the timeit while testing, but maybe I made a mistake. Thanks you